# How to Pass Prop to a Component That is being Iterated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, in Portfolio component, counter prop is not getting displayed, but stock prop is getting displayed fine. Portfolio component is getting mapped by stockInfo to receive props, but I added another separate prop called counter, but it's not working out. What would be the correct way to pass down counter prop to Portfolio component, when Portfolio component is being iterated by another prop?

```
function App() {
  const [stockInfo, setStockInfo] = useState([{ quote: "SPY", cost:320, currentHolding: true }]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  let showChart = true;

  const addStockSymbol = (quote, cost) => {    
    const newStockInfo = [...stockInfo, { quote: quote, cost: Number(cost), currentHolding: true }];
    setStockInfo(newStockInfo);
    setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <PortfolioForm addStockSymbol={addStockSymbol} />
      {stockInfo.map((stock, index) => (
        <div>
            <Portfolio 
            key = {index}
            index = {index}
            stock={stock}
            counter={counter}
            /> 
        </div>           
      ))}
    </div>     
  )
}

export default App;


import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Portfolio.css';

const Portfolio = ({stock}, {counter}) => {
const [stockData, setStockData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const data = await axios(
            `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${stock.quote}&token=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
          );
            setStockData(data.data);
        })();
    },[]);

    console.log(counter);

    return (
        <ul className="table-headings">
            <li>{counter}</li>
            <li>{stock.quote}</li>
            <li>${stockData.pc}</li>
            <li>${stock.cost}</li>
            <li>320 days</li>
            <li>36.78%</li>
        </ul>    
    )
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "counter prop is not getting displayed" , can you elaborate on this. The code looks ok for counter prop getting pased to Portfolio Component, put Portfolio component code here as well.

Comment: I agree I would log the `counter` prop in `Portfolio` and double check if there are no issues at the render side. You could also share the component implementation

Comment: What you have appears to be syntactically correct. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-props-to-mapped-component-sdrg2?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark). There may be something going in within your `Portfolio` component, can you update your question with `Portfolio`'s component code?

Comment: don't use `index` for a key: use something like `stock.id` or some other unique indicator

Comment: So I added Portfolio component code to original question. When I log counter in Portfolio component, I get undefined. I'm expecting 1 to be displayed, since that's the default  state. I thought this part was straightforward. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function components get `props` as argument, then you can destruct the props object to get only specific properties.

What you're doing right now in the `Portfolio` component is destructing `stock` from the `props` object (which is fine), but for `counter` you're destructing the second argument (which is also an object that represents [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), but in this case there is not ref so its an empty object)

So, to fix the problem, just replace the `Portfolio` parameters from `({stock}, {counter})` to `({stock, counter})` which destructs these two properties from `props`

You can learn more about destructuring assignment in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Yes, destructuring was the issue. Thanks!